Octave can't import sympy
I am on Mac M1 and I installed Octave with homebrew and need the Symbolic package.
The Symbolic package depends on sympy.
I installed sympy with pipx and my .zshrc file is this:
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/(user)/.local/bin"
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/Users/(user)/.local/pipx/venvs/sympy/lib/python3.13/site-packages"

When I type help("modules") on python3 in the terminal (/opt/homebrew/bin/python3), sympy appears.
But when I run Octave and type setenv PYTHON /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 and pkg load symbolic, the result of symspref diagnose is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    import sympy; print(sympy.__version__)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'
status = 1
output =


Is python3 executable in /opt/homebrew/bin/? Although that was the recommended path given by the octave installer, I had installed python much earlier than octave by some other means I don't even remember so I had to search for the actual path to python3 (e.g., by whereis python3).

Found the answer:
I added to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/octave/9.2.0_1/share/octave/site/m/startup/octaverc the lines:
setenv("PYTHON", "/opt/homebrew/bin/python3")
setenv("PYTHONPATH", [getenv("HOME")"/.local/pipx/venvs/sympy/lib/python3.13/site-packages"])


bravo on the self-Answer! please mark it with the check to the left!
